# Установка эмулятора/аддона SamsungGalaxy Tab на Android Studio

Tags: android-sdk, android, jetbrains

Здравствуйте!

Есть официальный плагин эмулятора Samsung Galaxy Tab (http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-GALAXY-Tab-Emulator). Так вот, на сайте подробно расписано как настроить плагин на Eclipse.

Возник такой вопрос: Как настроить этот самый эмулятор на AndroidStudio JetBrains?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Я вижу на сайте инструкцию, как установить это дело в AVD Manager, который к эклипсу отношения не имеет, это часть Android SDK.

Comment: Перефразирую вопрос. На MacOS я вижу Android SDK и AVD Manager как отдельные части. Я не вижу Android SDK and AVD Manager, А следовательно, я не вижу пункта - Available packages